# Retrieve input(s) from DataTable

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Need some advice how should I retrieve a list of exhibits.

In my html template below, I only put one record of exhibit. If i were to put additional rows/records of exhibit, how do i go about mapping them to the controller.

HTML Template

```
<h3>Exhibit Details</h3>

        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table id="exhibitTable"
                class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Exhibit Type</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Marking</th>
                        <th>Remarks</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <div class="cols-sm-10">
                                    <select class="form-control selectpicker cols-md-3"
                                        th:value="${exhibit.exhibitType}" id="exhibitType"
                                        name="exhibitType" roleId="exhibitType">
                                        <option value="">Select Type</option>
                                        <option>Desktop</option>
                                        <option>Laptop</option>
                                        <option>Mobile Device</option>
                                        <option>Portable Storage</option>
                                        <option>Server</option>
                                        <option>Video System</option>
                                        <option>Save As</option>
                                        <option>Others</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" name="exhibitDescription"
                                    id="exhibitDescription"
                                    th:value="${exhibit.exhibitDescription}" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" name="exhibitMarking" id="exhibitMarking"
                                    th:value="${exhibit.exhibitMarking}" />
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td><div class="form-group col-md-3">
                                <input type="text" name="exhibitRemarks" id="exhibitRemarks"
                                    th:value="${exhibit.exhibitRemarks}" />
                            </div></td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String registerIncidentPost(@ModelAttribute("incident") Incident incident,
            @ModelAttribute("exhibit") Exhibit exhibit, Principal principal) throws Exception {

        long year = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR);
        incident.setIncidentYear(year + "");

        Long refNo = incidentService.findMaxRefNoCurrentYear(year + "");
        if (refNo == null)
            refNo = (long) 1;
        else
            refNo += 1;
        incident.setIncidentRefNo(refNo);

        incident.setIncidentStatus(Incident.INCIDENT_REGISTERED);

        incident.setIncidentOpeningTimestamp(new Date());

        User user = userService.findByUsername(principal.getName());
        incident.setIncidentCreatedBy(user);

        incidentService.createIncident(incident);

            exhibitService.createExhibit(exhibit);

        return "redirect:/incident";
    }
```

I've attempted to add the following to my template
`<tr data-th-each="exhibit:${exhibitList}">`

and the following to my controller
`@ModelAttribute("exhibitList") ArrayList<Exhibit> exhibitList`

but did not work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I can only assume this is vb.net since you didn't specify.  You need to pass in the complete dataset to the page.  Each item in the dataset will be one pre-loaded instance of the model.  Then you can do a for each loop on the page itself and generate the html dynamically.  Hope this helps.